# Remove duplicates fetched from while loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am hoping to remove duplicate entries from an array that I am calling from a stored procedure with a while loop.

```
// Prepare stored procedure call
   $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL sp_get_recipes()'); 

   // Call the stored procedure
    $res = $sth->execute();

    if ($res){                  
        while( $row = $sth->fetchObject() ){
            echo $row->Recipe;  // I would like to echo this row just once.
            echo '<ul class="recipe-body"><li>'.$row->Ingredient."&nbsp;".$row->Quantity."&nbsp;".$row->UoM.'</li></ul>';
            }
        // Close connection
            $dbh = null;
        }else{
        $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
        echo "Execution failed with MYSQL: " . $arr[0] . "\n";
        die();
        }
```

My understanding is my echo $row->Recipe; has to exist on it's own somehow. I've being looking into array_unique to echo the value just once but I can't seem to figure it out exactly. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be great.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all the responses I have fixed up the stored procedure to return unique rows.

Comment: How about returning unique rows from the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary array before the while and store every Recipe in it which have been echoed. Before the echo check the temporary array for the current Recipe (if it contains don't echo it otherwaise echo & store it in the temporary array).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the database structure, which I would recommend, you could first store the information you get from the database query into objects (e.g. some kind of Recipe objects with an array of Ingredient objects) and then build your actual output.

If you can change the database structure or the way you query (if the latter already gives you what I'm about to recommend) you can have a table (assuming the database is relational) for the recipes with some kind of ID and another table for the ingredients of the recipes where each ingredient row also stores the ID of the recipe it belongs to.